# laravel будет ли лагать такой запрос, и как это исправить

Tags: база-данных, laravel, cron, schedule

Есть такие таблицы `users`, `eggs`, `birds`, `sellers`, `certificates`
Каждый час или даже лучше каждые 10 минут мне нужно изменять и добавлять записи в таблицу `eggs`.

Для этого я сделал scheduler, запись cron и command, в которой такой запрос

```js
public function handle() {
  // Метод возвращает массив  данных из таблиц birds и seller->certificates
  $birds_users = User::get_all_users_birds_with_certificate();

  // перебираем все это
  foreach($birds_users as $key => $birds_user) {
    // получаем пользователя по key (key - это user id)
    $user = User::with('my_eggs') -> find($key);

    // теперь перебираем каждую птицу пользователя по отдельности
    foreach($birds_user[0] as $bird) {
      // проверяем есть ли уже такая запись
      if (
        $user -> my_eggs -> contains('user_id', '===', $key) &&
        $user -> my_eggs -> contains('bird_seller_id', '===', $bird["bird_seller_id"])
      ) {
        // берем эту запись
        $birdRow = Egg::where('user_id', $key) - > where('bird_seller_id', $bird["bird_seller_id"]) - > first();

        // и обновляем нужные поля
        $birdRow - > demand = $bird["demand"]; // if the characteristics of the bird will change
        $birdRow - > count += $bird["count"] * $bird["fertility"]; // increase eggs
        $birdRow - > update();
      } else {
        // такой записи еще нет, нужно ее создать
        Egg::create([
          'user_id' => $key,
          'bird_seller_id' => $bird["bird_seller_id"],
          'price' => $bird["egg_price"],
          'demand' => $bird["demand"],
          'count' => $bird["count"] * $bird["fertility"],
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ТО есть получается, что каждый час (или 10 минут) получаем каждого пользователя по отдельности, для каждой его птицы так же выполняем запрос. Это может вызывать большую нагрузку? Если да, то как это можно исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю так делать не следует. Гонять данные между веб-сервером и сервером базы данных для массовых обновлений - не лучшее решение. Нужно писать сырой запрос и отсылать его серверу базы данных, пусть он там у себя все быстренько сделает.

В качестве отправной точки для написания запроса:

1. [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)
2. [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: Ну да, это логично.  Думаю, стоит действительно писать сырой запрос. Но, думаю, он получится очень и очень сложным) Если я правильно понимаю, то в идеале писать только один запрос? Не стоит получать птиц, потом получать пользователей, а потом обновлять это всё? Получается же тоже самое. Нужно именно одним запросом всё это сделать?

Comment: Да, нужно одним запросом. "Очень и очень сложный" - это все относительно :-) На моей практике были случаи, что действительно приходилось пользоваться SQL-комментариями, так как запрос составлял порядка 10 печатных страниц. Правда это на PostgreSQL'е. Начнешь писать, разбираться, войдешь во вкус, потом не оторвать будет)

Comment: Можешь написать мне в вк?) Я начал писать запрос, и есть пару вопросиков) https://vk.com/color_kat

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста. у меня получилось достать все нужные мне данные и считать нужные данные, например, bird.price * certificate.price_bonus. Но мне нужно эти данные вставить в таблицу. То есть `INSERT INTO` данных из `SELECT` да еще как-то изменённых. Как это можно сделать.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LoK0Z8b.png - запрос на обновление (работает), https://i.imgur.com/3MW9jx7.png - INSERT запрос, вот тут проблемы

Comment: Сорри, я не пользуюсь соцсетями.

Comment: Честно говоря, нет сейчас времени вникать. Но если все же будет засада, тогда отредактируй свой вопрос - добавь туда DDL твоей БД в сыром виде, ну или опубликуй миграции и посевы Laravel, и нужный алгоритм манипуляции с данными.

Comment: Я с этим разобрался уже сам) Но появился другой вопрос. Я вставляю данные в таблицу (`INSERT INTO eggs (c1,c2) SELECT v1, v2 FROM  ... 1) И если такие данные есть, то мне нужно обновить их, как это сделать? https://i.imgur.com/21q2cgh.png

Comment: Вторая ссылка в моем ответе, там об этом вопросе вроде. Повторюсь, без DDL  (или миграций и посевов) и описании нужной обработки - ничего не подскажу.

Comment: Нет, в ссылке on duplicate key - чтобы оно работало, мне нужно вставлять id самому

Comment: Если в таблице есть поля с автоинкрементом (а я незнаю), можно попробовать этот механизм - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Нет, replace into, как я понял, тоже работает на том ,что id совпадает. Ну короче я сделал, что id для таблицы eggs генерируется как `CONCAT(user.id, bird_seller.id)`. Я сделаю ответ, добавлю туда запрос, если интересно)

Answer (score 1):

Да, посылать такие запросы через laravel - не лучшая идея. Нужно написать один сырой sql запрос. Сначала было страшно приступать к этому, так как в sql я писал только SELECT, иногда UPDATE. А тут куча связей. Но потом оказалось, что это не так и страшно, даже интересно)

```js
INSERT INTO eggs (id, name, birds_count, price, demand, count, litter, collected, user_id, bird_seller_id)

SELECT 
    CONCAT(u.id, b_s.id), -- create UID from user_id and bird_seller_id
    birds.name, -- bird name
    count, -- count of birds from bird_seller_user table
    birds.egg_price * (1 + IFNULL(price_bonus, 0) / 100), -- egg price with certificate
    birds.demand * (1 + IFNULL(demand_bonus, 0) / 100), -- demand with certificate bonus
    count * birds.fertility * (1 + IFNULL(fertility_bonus, 0) / 100), -- get count of eggs from birds_count * fertility with certificate bonus
    count * birds.litter * (1 + IFNULL(litter_bonus, 0) / 100),
    0, -- change collected
    user_id,
    bird_seller_id 
    
FROM users AS u -- get all users

LEFT JOIN bird_seller_user AS b_s_u ON (b_s_u.user_id = u.id) -- join bird_seller_user table to get sold_bird

JOIN bird_seller AS b_s ON (b_s.id = b_s_u.bird_seller_id) -- join bird_seller table (this id sol_bird)

JOIN birds ON (b_s.bird_id = birds.id) -- join birds table

LEFT JOIN certificates AS certs ON ((SELECT certificate_id FROM sellers WHERE id = b_s.seller_id) = certs.id) -- and join certificate table

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    name = birds.name, -- update bird name (just in case)
    birds_count = b_s_u.count,
    price = birds.egg_price * (1 + IFNULL(price_bonus, 0) / 100),
    demand = birds.demand,
    count = eggs.count + b_s_u.count * birds.fertility * (1 + IFNULL(fertility_bonus, 0) / 100), -- increase eggs count
    litter = b_s_u.count * birds.litter * (1 + IFNULL(litter_bonus, 0) / 100),
    collected = 0
```

через join связываем все таблицы, аналог belongsTo в ларе,
Вставляем эти данные через INSERT INTO.
А через `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` обновляем запись, если она уже есть (Он работает, если совпадает id)